# Multiple API requests using Axios ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

y'all..!
I am trying to make multiple requests to stockTweet API with an array of endpoints.
I have used a for loop to fire the requests, there should be a better way.
searchTerm = [aapl, amzn, pypl] --- no restriction on number of terms.

https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/aapl.json

https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/amzn.json

https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/pypl.json

the number of requests is dynamic.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import SearchBar from "./Searchbar";
import Card from "./Card";

const apiUrl = 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol';
  const headers = {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  };

class App extends React.Component{

  state = {};


    // --------------------------STATE--------------------------
    // {
    //     Apple.Inc: [
    //         {
    //             id: 111111,
    //             body: "aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbb ccccccc dddd",
    //             createdAt: timeStamp
    //         }
    //         {
    //             id: 222222,
    //             body: "aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbb ccccccc dddd",
    //             createdAt: timeStamp
    //         }
    //     ],
    //     Amazon.com: [
    //         {
    //             id: 333333,
    //             body: "aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbb ccccccc dddd",
    //             createdAt: timeStamp
    //         }
    //         {
    //             id: 444444,
    //             body: "aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbb ccccccc dddd",
    //             createdAt: timeStamp
    //         }
    //     ],
    // }


    onSearchSubmit = async (term) => {
      term = term.split(', ');
      for(let i = 0; i < term.length; i++){
        let symbol = term[i];
        const stocktwitsQuery = `${apiUrl}/${symbol}.json`;
        const resp = await axios.get(stocktwitsQuery, headers);
        let tweets = [];
        let allTweetsBody = res.data.messages.map((oneTweet) => tweets.push(oneTweet)); //add the tweet body to array
        this.setState({ ...this.state, [this.state[res.data.symbol['title']]]:  tweets });        
      }
    }


  render() {
    return( 
      <div className="ui container" style={{marginTop:'10px'}}>
          <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

How would I do that? TIA

P.S. Code is messed up..! :(

Comment: You can use promise.all to make it looks more cleaner, instead of using for-loop which isn't the best way to handle it

Comment: I can do Promise.all(), if I know how many requests are being made. Length of searchTerm is not defined, it can be 1, or 2 or n.

Comment: So you can generate the array and pass into promise.all(urlArr). I hope it fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

This should work for n number of terms. Just split the terms into array and pass it as argument into `promise.all`

```js
const termUrls = terms.split(', ');
Promise.all(termsUrls).then((responses) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The downside of using `promise.all` in your case is that if one of your APIs is down so then your `promise.all` will reject all other ones. In your case, you could use `promise.allSettled()`

The **`Promise.allSettled()`** method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either been fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

It is typically used when you have multiple asynchronous tasks that are not dependent on one another to complete successfully, or you'd always like to know the result of each promise.

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 100, 'foo'));
const promises = [promise1, promise2];

Promise.allSettled(promises).
  then((results) => results.forEach((result) =>  console.log(result.status)));

// expected output:
// "fulfilled"
// "rejected"
```